# SkyStar S2 has a mac address, for what?

Tags: receiver, satellites

Hy just a "stupid" question, I bought a technisat skystar s2 pci card.
Can any body tell me why this thing has a mac address printed on it? ^^
And the mac address can even been looked up. (00-08-c9-xx-xx-xx)

Is it possible to receive/transmitt ethernet packets and if so is it possible to use this data link via atv(HAM TV - Digital).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not even remotely related to amateur radio

Comment: hy why do you think it isn't even remotely related to amateur radio? Basicly it is a radio receiver and i'm wondering why this thing has a mac address(from a technical aspeckt)?

Comment: [Amateur radio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amateur_radio) is a specific field (a “radio service” in formal terms), not just “the use of radio equipment by non-professionals”. [Other uses of radio technology are specifically off-topic here.](http://ham.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) We do welcome questions about radio _theory, in general_ but this is a question about a particular piece of non-amateur equipment which you don't seem to be planning to repurpose.

Comment: Without context, you are simply asking for technical information for consumer electronic equipment. If you had put it into an amateur radio context (intention to use as SDR or similar) that might be slightly different, but as it stands the question is not related to amateur radio.

Comment: Ok i got it ^^ So yes the intention of this question is, for what does it have the mac address and can it be used for other radio receiver designes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because Skystar card works as a network device. Physical layer is DVB-S signal on 1.2 GHz band comming from parabolic antenna converting from Ku or C band via LNB. Data stream is only downlink (no uplink or packet acknowlegment) and there are used error-correction codes based on Reed-Solomon which help to recover data on reception side (sometimes it is not possible because 10 GHz Ku-band does not "like" heavy rain :)

I was using this card for reception of Meteosat images via EUMETCAST. Eumetsat distributes satellite data to users via a regular TV satellite (it was Hotbird6, not it is Eurobird9). So on the one frequency, there are many multicast data streams identified via Packet ID (they IP addresses started with 224.223.xxx.xxx). I was using Linux, so there were many virtual ethernet devices for each PID linked binded with Skystar driver and routed to final dummy0 device by smcroute. Special software Tellicast is used for storing files on disk (they are usually encrypted and you need to be registered and have a hardware key) and another software for data decompression and display.

More info about Meteosat reception is on my homepage: http://bruxy.regnet.cz/web/meteosat/

Answer (score 0):

The DVB-T2 standard specifies (many things and ) an ethernet controler, that's all ...